# Google Charts scatter plots work on Chrome Macbook but not on Chrome iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, google-visualization, data-science

Help!

Been scouring the internet trying to figure out why the plots below would show on a laptop or desktop via Chrome, Firefox, and even IE but not on iPhone 8 Plus Chrome? Thank you in advance!

Works on Macbook Chrome:
[Macbook iOS Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb292.png)

Even Macbook's Chrome Dev Tools using a mobile view:
[Macbook iOS Chrome Mobile Dev Tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rSGd.png)

But not in the Chrome browser when viewing on iPhone 8 Plus?
[Individual data points on chart aren't shown mobile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbUcR.jpg)

Code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Google Charts loader -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
    </script>
    <!-- Google Charts creator and renderer -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['scatter']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);

        function drawCharts() {
            drawChart0();
            drawChart1();
            drawChart2();
        };

        function drawChart0 ()
        {
            var data0 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data0.addColumn('date', 'Date');
            data0.addColumn('number', 'Price');
            data0.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 06:57:31'),1450]);
            data0.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 08:35:31'),1070]);
            data0.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 09:27:50'),1454]);
            data0.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 09:29:54'),1475]);
            data0.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 10:48:23'),1099]);
            data0.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 10:56:35'),1195]);
            data0.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 11:01:04'),1375]);
            data0.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 11:01:10'),1399]);
            data0.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 11:02:15'),1175]);

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'Studio Rent Prices'
                },
                hAxis: {title: 'Date of Price'},
                vAxis: {title: 'Price ($)'}
            };
            var chart0 = new google.charts.Scatter(document.getElementById('scatterchart0'));
            chart0.draw(data0, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));
        };


        function drawChart1 ()
        {
            var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data1.addColumn('date', 'Date');
            data1.addColumn('number', 'Price');
            data1.addRow([new Date('2018-02-27 13:08:49'),1550]);
            data1.addRow([new Date('2018-02-27 14:14:46'),1550]);
            data1.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 11:02:11'),1875]);
            data1.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 11:56:38'),1875]);
            data1.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 12:54:21'),2310]);
            data1.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 13:11:34'),1834]);
            data1.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 14:10:52'),1709]);
            data1.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 15:04:39'),1595]);
            data1.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 15:05:36'),1715]);

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'One Bedroom Rent Prices'
                },
                hAxis: {title: 'Date of Price'},
                vAxis: {title: 'Price ($)'}
            };
            var chart1 = new google.charts.Scatter(document.getElementById('scatterchart1'));
            chart1.draw(data1, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));
        };

        function drawChart2 ()
        {
            var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data2.addColumn('date', 'Date');
            data2.addColumn('number', 'Price');

            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 07:15:20'),1550]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 09:37:37'),2164]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 11:05:15'),1850]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 11:15:27'),2150]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-03-01 13:13:26'),2265]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-04-02 15:46:59'),1495]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-04-05 08:02:41'),1650]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-04-05 09:45:10'),2919]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-04-06 17:17:32'),1725]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-04-09 09:58:12'),1550]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-04-09 14:17:45'),1995]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-04-12 10:57:25'),2395]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-04-16 07:56:38'),1550]);
            data2.addRow([new Date('2018-04-19 09:37:20'),1850]);

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'Two Bedroom Rent Prices'
                },
                hAxis: {title: 'Date of Price'},
                vAxis: {title: 'Price ($)'}
            };
            var chart2 = new google.charts.Scatter(document.getElementById('scatterchart2'));
            chart2.draw(data2, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));
        };
    </script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet'>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Lato';
            font-size: 22px;
            margin: 10px;
            margin-left: 40px;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rent Price Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Rent Details</h2>
    <h3 id='ToC'>Table of Contents</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#Studio' target='_self'>Studio Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href='#1Bed' target='_self'>1 Bedroom Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href='#2Bed' target='_self'>2 Bedroom Prices</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h4 id='Studio'>Studio Prices</h4>
    <div id='scatterchart0' style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div><br />
    <h4 id='1Bed'>1 Bedroom Prices</h4>
    <div id='scatterchart1' style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div><br />
    <h4 id='2Bed'>2 Bedroom Prices</h4>
    <div id='scatterchart2' style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div><br />
    </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart#methods)  ...in particular method `getChartLayoutInterface`, in order to check if not the chart is being rendered outside of the visible viewport, due to a wrongful measurement, resulting in a wrongful positioning. also, there is the possibility, that DOM events with different names (as expected) might be triggered by the mobile browser, which would need to be mapped to the chart's events... does the chart fire any `ready` or `error` event ??

the screenshot does not exactly look alike as if SVG wouldn't be supported.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear what you are suggesting. Do I need to set each chart to a specific visual boundary so it shows on the browser via the function you mentioned?

Comment: you'll have to check (not yet adjust anything), if the chart is being drawn within the visual boundaries of the canvas; use Chrome debug bridge, in order to debug the mobile browser; it's `chrome://inspect` - while having a data cable connected... the other possibility are the events, where one might not be triggered correctly on the browser. with debug bridge both can be debugged, then fixed.

Comment: Maybe you can point me to an article where someone can do the above? I'm not seeing any understandable docs on this topic or how to even correct it in JS if a chart is not being drawn within the visual canvas. Thank you!

Comment: @ZacharyOliver I've already pointed you to an URL, which in general "has all the answers"... here it is explained better: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ and I guess that should work with Chrome on iPhone, too. the point is that special hardware is required to reproduce "your problem" - therefore chances are low, that someone will try to reproduce and fix it for you. filing a bug against the chart component might be the other option.